# Why these integrals are evaluated differently? $\cos(x)/(a-b\cos(x))$

Tags: integration, mathematica

In attempt to solve electrostatics problem I came up to this integral that I am trying to integrate:

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos(x)}{a-b\cos(x)} \, dx$$ where $a>b$ and both are real numbers.

For the domain $[0, 2\pi]$ this function is symmetric at $\pi$ (Plot: [1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Cos%5Bx%5D/%283%20-%202%2aCos%5Bx%5D%29))

So it is expected that:

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos(x)}{a-b\cos(x)}dx = 2\int_0^{\pi}\frac{\cos(x)}{a-b\cos(x)}dx$$

I could not integrate it by hand (maybe some of you guys can?). But Wolfram Mathematica gives weird answers for both of these integrals - however if evaluated they lead to same answer!

This is what Mathematica gives me:

$$\int_0^{2 \pi } \frac{\cos (x)}{a-b \cos (x)} \, dx = \frac{2 \pi  \left(a \left(\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{a-b}}-1\right)-b\right)}{b (a+b)}$$

$$\int_0^{\pi } \frac{\cos (x)}{a-b \cos (x)} \, dx = -\frac{\frac{a \log \left(\frac{a+b}{\sqrt{b^2-a^2}}\right)}{\sqrt{b^2-a^2}}-\frac{a \log \left(-\frac{a+b}{\sqrt{b^2-a^2}}\right)}{\sqrt{b^2-a^2}}+\pi }{b}$$

If I add these logarithms it gives log(-1) which is imaginary, how come these integrals are the same?

Comment: Have you looked into the Weierstrass substitution?

Comment: @imranfat : As has been discussed in this forum before, the tangent half-angle substitution gets called "the Weierstrass substitution" erroneously and perhaps only because the error has radiated out from just one source: Stewart's calculus textbook.  Stewart, like all pop stars, is hiding in a cave in Afghanistan, so my letter to him asking what his source is for naming it after Weierstrass was sent to him in care of his editor.  Neither he nor his editor answered, so I'll ask the editor if the letter ever reached him.

Comment: @MichaelHardy You may be right but does it matter that much? The Pythagoran theorem wasn't discovered by Pythagoras, L'Hospital's rule wasn't discovered by him either. Stewart is not the only source crediting him for that but I readily admit that I got it from that book. I myself learned it as the tangent half angle substitution in my school days but our prof never even mentioned who came up with it.

Comment: @imranfat : But did those other sources merely get it from Stewart?  If he's the original source, maybe it's not too late to nip it in the bud (unlike the case of Pythagoras).

Comment: @MichaelHardy. I studied abroad and Weierstrass is credited by others as well. Not where I studied, I just learned it as the tangent half angle approach with no person's name attached to it, but honestly the first time I read about that Weierstrass supposedly figured this out was indeed from a Stewart textbook (shame on me...) I though, well well, that's nice to know until the truth seems to be little different. And I do not think that Weierstrass' qualities really depend on this substitution either...

Answer (score 0):

These integrals are very similar to the ones for which Euler introduced the tangent half-angle substitution, sometimes erroneously called the "Weierstrass substitution" (I hope the quotation marks are intimidating . . . . .)

\begin{align}
t & = \tan\frac x 2 \\[8pt]
2\arctan(t) & = x \\[8pt]
\frac{2\,dt}{1+t^2} & = dx \\[8pt]
\cos x & = \cos(2\arctan t) = 2\cos^2(\arctan t) - 1 \\[8pt]
& = 2\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}\right)^2 - 1 = \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}
\end{align}
(and $\sin x$ can be found similarly, but we don't need it here, and neither did Euler in the integrals he did this way that I am aware of).

So we have
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\cos x}{a-b\cos x}\,dx & = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}}{a-b\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}}\cdot\frac{2\,dt}{1+t^2} \\[8pt]
& = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1-t^2}{a(1+t^2)^2- b(1+t^2)(1-t^2)} 2\,dt
\end{align}
$$

One of the factors of the denominator is $1+t^2$. Another depends on $a$ and $b$.

Now go on to partial fractions.  If $a>b>0$, you'll have two irreducible quadratic factors in the denominators, so you'll get some arctangents and maybe also some logarithms.